# Finite Differences - determine degree of the equation when the abscissas aren't consecutive

Tags: finite-differences

The question is:

Given the set of points,

(2, -8)
(4, -240)
(6, -1272)
(7,-2373)
(8, -4046)
(10, -9960)
(12, -20688)

determine the degree of the equation.

However I am given values at 2, 4, 6 etc so the method of finite differences cant' be used so have just concentrated on the three points at 6,7,8 but can't find.

Comment: Have you tried using finite differences on x = 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12?

Comment: Yes I have and it doesn't work out to a constant difference - however to use the method of finite differences the x has to be consecutive so can't use x-2,4,6,8,10,12 - the clue is in the 6,7,8 but it is eluding me right now

Comment: That's not true - x doesn't need to be "consecutive".  Think about it - if P is a polynomial over the reals, why should a spacing of "1" be special in any way?

Comment: the method of finite differences and the difference table states that it is n then (n+1), (n+2) ....

Comment: Do you have any idea why it works?  If you understand why it is true it should be clear that it works the same way for n+k, n+2k, etc.

Comment: Furthermore, it's also true that for any k points, I can find a degree n polynomial going through all of them if for any sufficiently large n, so there is no unique answer.  Are you looking for the minimum possible degree?

Comment: If so, you know by finite differences on 2, 4, 6... that it's greater than 4, and since there are 7 points that it's at most 6.

Comment: ahhh, I think it is in that it is greater than 4 but at most six